# Finding the most frequent element

Tags: algorithm, comparison

There are several colors of balls. For one specific color, there are more than half of the balls with this color(>n/2). How can I find this color taking only O(n) running time?

Comment: Why don't you just count and deduce result after `n`? Its `O(n)`.

Comment: By that means, it will take O(n^2) times. You have to compare the ball in your hand with the ball in the holes one by one.

Comment: No no, every time you pick a ball, just increment the count of that color. In the end, check which color is the greatest. You can also improvise on this by comparing on the fly :) `O(n)` since you traverse the array only once. Look up `treeMap` too, OR Red, Black Trees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Boyer-Moore majority algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html)

Comment: +1 This one is clearly the best! And it's a very nice algorithm, too :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Isn't this almost what you said ? I don't see any big difference.

Comment: @noMAD Well, Boyer-Moore is by far easier to code, much easier to understand, and although it's not asymptotically faster, it will probably have a much smaller constant in front of `N`.

Comment: @noMAD Majority algorithm is much simpler and faster to code then selection algorithm. Also - the "quick select" method is O(n^2) on worst case, and median of medians is usually unpractical because of horrible constants. The majority algorithm requires a single iteration on the elements, and is very simple and efficient. Its sequential behavior is also making it very cache efficient.

Comment: Are you sure the implementation on that website actually finds the majority element? What would it do in the sequence AAAAACCCCBB? It seems to me it would find B as the majority element, while it clearly isn't..

Comment: @Joost Yes, I'm sure that algo does work. Concerning your example - there are no majority element in this string

Comment: Ah, mea culpa. Thought it was looking for the most frequently occuring element, but it's explicitly looking for the one that occurs for more than 50%. My bad. Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Find the color of each ball and tally it up. This doesn't seem to be a sorting at all if you only want to find the most frequent. Just count the number of balls with each color. You could use a hashtable, key is the color and just iterate the spot. Also keep track of the colors.

Edit:
After reading this again, I realized that it did not answer the question.

A) You could just do the tracking at the end by iterating through every available color (assuming you were making that list of colors), as there will be less than n comparisons, it will in the worse case be O(n).

B) While you are tallying the ball count up, keep track of the largest count. Whenever that gets beat, replace it with the current color with the highest count. You probably want to keep track of the color along with the highest number. This way you will do it on a comparison on every run. This again will be O(n) but will have more comparisons.

Comment: The point is, when the number of colors is (n/2-1), it will take O(n^2) times to count the number of balls with each color, because you have to scan all the color to compare.

Comment: No it doesn't. Run through your list ONCE and increment counters. Running time is O(N)

Comment: @Mile let n be the number of comparisons. Tallying up does not count as an action. There are n comparisons. O(n).

Or if you want to count tallying up and comparisons, it will be O(2*n) which is still O(n).